# Display metrics for multiple namespaces

Tags: grafana

Created a Grafana dashboard, that shows the memory usage of specific application pod(s) but for a single namespace.

I would like to display the memory usage of an application pod for all the available namespaces on a single dashboard. Is this achievable ?

Datasource - `Prometheus`

Query :

A - `sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{cluster="$cluster", namespace="$namespace", container!="", image!=""}) by (pod)`

B - `scalar(kube_resourcequota{cluster="$cluster", namespace="$namespace", type="hard",resource="requests.memory"})`

Comment: Most likely. What is your data source, and what is your query?

Comment: @markalex:  Sorry, I've updated that on the question.

Comment: Query B seems to show maximum available quota of memory. But I assume they might be different for different namespaces. Should all of them be displayed at the same time?

Comment: Correct, all of them should be displayed at the same time for any given pod, let it be CPU or memory consumption.

Comment: @markalex : following query returns memory usage of all pod in every namespace - `sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{container!=""}) by (namespace, pod)` but I'm trying to achieve is get memory usage for a single pod across all namespaces